# realm throws error that object was deleted

Tags: swift, realm

I need to delete object from realm. But when I do that, it throws an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'

Here is my code:

```
           if let character = character {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if !character.isInvalidated { // Check if the object is still valid
                            try? self.realm.write {
                                self.realm.delete(character)
                            }
                        
                    } else {
                        print("Object has already been deleted or invalidated.")
                    }
                    self.leaveThisPage()
                }
            }
```

I tried to use `isInvalidated` to check if it is already deleted, so it works first two times, and then throws error. I also tried to use

```
if let character = realm.object(ofType: MyCharacterObjectModel.self, forPrimaryKey: characterID) {
                
            }
```

but the same effect.

Comment: any chance this gets called more than once ?

Comment: no, only once for object

Comment: More than likely you're using `character` somewhere else - perhaps in an array or elsewhere. The code in the question does not crash for us so the issue is not duplicating with that code. Also, why this `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Update the question with details and a duplicatable example and we'll take a look!